# How to find multiple strings between tag/sub-strings?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, substring

I have a string which has defined tags around specific words or sub-strings. For example:

```
text = 'Bring me to <xxx>ibis and the</xxx> in <ccc>NW</ccc> and the <sss>Jan</sss> 
<hhh>10</hhh>'
```

How can I get the strings `<xxx>ibis and the</xxx>`, `<ccc>NW</ccc>`, `<sss>Jan</sss>` and `<hhh>10</hhh>`. These tags can be anything but the tags covering a word or few words will be similar. Also, if a start or end tag is missing, I don't want that string to be returned. For example:

```
text = 'Bring me to <xxx>ibis and the in NW</ccc> and the <sss>Jan</sss> 
<hhh>10</hhh>'
```

In this case, only `<sss>Jan</sss>` and `<hhh>10</hhh>` has to be returned.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:nsregularexpression]? Are you running Python on iOS or something?

Comment: @Mast Corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you don't want regex to parse (X)HTML ([more info in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)) Better option is using a parser. This example is with `beautifulsoup`:

```
data = '''text = 'Bring me to <xxx>ibis and the</xxx> in <ccc>NW</ccc> and the <sss>Jan</sss>
<hhh>10</hhh>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('xxx, ccc, sss, hhh'):
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
ibis and the
NW
Jan
10
```

EDIT: To get whole tag string:

```
for tag in soup.select('xxx, ccc, sss, hhh'):
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
<xxx>ibis and the</xxx>
<ccc>NW</ccc>
<sss>Jan</sss>
<hhh>10</hhh>
```

EDIT II: If you have list of tags to find:

```
list_of_tags = ['xxx', 'ccc', 'sss', 'hhh']
for tag in soup.find_all(list_of_tags):
    print(tag)
```

EDIT: In case of malformed HTML it's necessary to change the parser:

```
data = '''text = 'Bring me to <xxx>ibis and the in NW</ccc> and the <sss>Jan</sss>
<hhh>10</hhh>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

list_of_tags = ['xxx', 'ccc', 'sss', 'hhh']
for tag in soup.find_all(list_of_tags):
    if tag.find_all(list_of_tags):
        continue
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
<sss>Jan</sss>
<hhh>10</hhh>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But I am sorry I should have asked my question in another way. I edited it now, could you please check it?

Comment: How to give the name of the tags ? Because when I give them as a list I am getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: @Dennis.M You use method `find_all()` See my answer. The documentation for BeautifulSoup can be found here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: How to avoid parsing the string if one of the tags is missing?

Comment: @Dennis.M What do you mean? Do you want to return all tags or nothing if just one is missing?